# Create user defined operator with left/right sides

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, operators

I'm starting to develop an Oracle operator with pl/sql. There are some examples in the guide but now I stick on something.

In all examples that I have seen, it's always like this :

```
CREATE OPERATOR Contains 
   BINDING (VARCHAR2, VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN NUMBER 
     USING text.contains;
```

and we use it like this in `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MyEmployees 
 WHERE Contains(resume, 'Oracle') = 1;
```

Is it possible to create an operator, which is used like `=, +, ...` with a left and a right side ?

In this case like :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MyEmployees 
 WHERE resume Contains 'Oracle'
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : 
I know it's possible with PostgreSQL, but didn't find for Oracle
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html

Comment: That would usually be referred to as an infix operator. I'm not familiar with Oracle so can't give an answer; But most languages I've encountered don't allow you to define *new* infix operators (usually they have to be handled carefully by the parser).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Postgres allows that ;) (And I think C++ as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpt from your comment to @ajmalmhd04 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20140815/997660)

> i really want to use my operator like built-in (=, + ...)

Yes, [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10800/dciudops.htm) is a bit confusing in the way it defines user-defined operators, especially this part:

> user-defined operators act like the built-in operators such as <, >, and =;

Unfortunately, it means that you can use user-defined operators where(mostly) you can use built-in operators but not in the same way(`operand1 OPERATOR operand2` for instance) you use built-in operators, like `<` or `=`. User-defined operators, if not look at them very very closely, are different way of calling functions with the exception that they(operators) can only be used in DML statements (`select`, `insert` and so forth). You won't be able to use them in PL/SQL directly, only through DML.
So, something like this, in PL/SQL will result in `PLS-00548: invalid use of operator.`

```
if operator(<<arguments>>) = 1 then
  -- something
end if;
```

The benefits of creating and using operators, if you are not involved in developing application specific server-based extensions (data cartridges), indextypes for instance, not that visible to me personally. Cannot think of a situation where you can use operators and cannot use functions. Opposite is not true, however.  You may look at operator's ability to have multiple bindings as a way of using it as an overloaded function. But, on the other hand, you can easily achieve the same with packages.

Answer (score 1):

1)create a `TYPE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE number_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

2) create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION near_to_num_f(A number) RETURN number_type AS
l_num number_type;
BEGIN
SELECT num
BULK COLLECT INTO l_num
FROM tab1 WHERE num + 15 >= a AND num -15 <= a;
RETURN l_num;
END;
```

3) create the operator:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE OPERATOR near_to
   BINDING (number) 
   RETURN number_type
   USING near_to_num_f;
```

4) Create sample table and insert some data:

```
 CREATE TABLE tab1 (num NUMBER);
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES( 90);
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES( 95);
insert into tab1 values( 120);
```

5) Query using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab1 
WHERE  num IN(select * from TABLE(near_to(100)));
```

6) Output:

```
 NUM
----------
  90 
  95
```

[Read More](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6004.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is the same i really want to use my operator like built-in (=, + ...). An arg leftside (the column) and rightside the value.

Comment: if you want to use as a built-in... I am not sure if it is possible, but you can try a wrapper to overcome typing braces