# Motivation behind User-Defined operators in Oracle Pl/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

What is the purpose of User-Defined operators in Oracle? Is there any context where the user-defined operators cannot be replaced with (or more preferable than) stored functions?

I'm reading Oracle documentation about [User-Defined operators](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/operators.htm#ADDCI2100) and I cannot really understand where one should use it.

Comment: The question is too broad.

Comment: I don’t agree that the question is too broad. It is not clear for me from Oracle Documentation, for what reasons the user-defined operators should be used instead of stored functions (syntactically and functionally they are absolutely the same). And I cannot see any reasons to define the operators either. So, probably I miss some topic in Pl/SQL which explains where operators are beneficial, and thus I’d like to fill this gap in knowledge.

Comment: According to @NicholasKrasnov they are not much of a use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20152667/272735 and I tend to agree. So not too broad but a duplicate <grin>.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov mentions server-based extensions (indextypes), so we can probably infer from his answer (can we?) that there are some cases when user-defined operators are essential. But please note that he answers completely different question, namely: "is it possible to define infix operator". So I don't agree that my question is a duplicate either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the only real reason you'd use a UDO rather than a function is to create an indextype, or to provide ancillary data to the query. The `CONTAINS` operator is a good example.

That said, I've never had any use of them myself.